# Android click notification to open web page

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open a web page when a notification is clicked:

```
public void shownNotification(String title, String message){
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    notifyIntent.setData(Uri.parse("htp://www.google.com"));
    PendingIntent pendingItent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, new Intent[] {notifyIntent }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingItent)
            .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```

I get the notification with out a problem but when I click it, it just bring me to the application.

Comment: You can set which Activity you want to go(Don't use MainActivity,class), Create a new activity, on loading it just open the browser or do what you want.

Comment: I am new to Android programming not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `notifyIntent` to:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yoururl.com"));
```

Then your code will be something like:

```
public void shownNotification(String title, String message){
    Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.yoururl.com"));
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent pendingItent = PendingIntent.getActivities(this, 0, new Intent[] {notifyIntent }, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(pendingItent)
            .build();
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
}
```